# Why was this question, which has two answers with positive scores, deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, moderation

[Is it a sin to have sex with promiscuous, unmarried women?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31747/is-it-a-sin-to-have-sex-with-promiscuous-unmarried-women-of-equal-caste-as-you/31763#31763)

This question was deleted. I was of the opinion that if a question has at least one answer that has a positive score it can not be deleted. Even if asker wants he/she can not delete the question.

So, is my thinking wrong? In what circumstances such a deletion is valid? Can users delete their own questions that has answers with positive scores? Can they request Mods to do it on their behalf and what should be the Mod's response in such cases?

EDIT:

Found this Meta SE post: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222)

This is relevant to what I am asking.

Users can not delete their questions in the following situations:

> **When can't I delete my own post?**
>
> Special note: You can't delete your own post using the iOS or Android
>   apps. You can, however, delete your post by using the app's option to
>   open the question in a Web browser and deleting it from there,
>   provided none of the below apply.
>
> - You can't delete your own answer if it has been accepted.
> - You can't delete your own question if it:
>
>   - has an answer with upvotes (even if that answer has a net zero or negative score)
> - has an accepted answer
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)
>
>   - has an answer with an awarded bounty
>
> You can't delete any of your questions or answers if you haven't
>   registered your account (that is, associated a Google, Facebook, or
>   Stack Exchange account with it).

So, in this case OP will not be able to delete the post.

He/she can still flag it requesting a Mod to delete it. In that case the answer says the Mod should decline such flags:

> **If I flag my question with a request to delete it, what will happen?**
>
> **The standard policy for moderators is to decline such flags**. The
>   reasoning is as follows:
>
> - If you can delete your question (because it has no answers, or the only answer has no upvotes), then you should do it. It does not
>     require moderator intervention. If you're using the mobile app (which
>     doesn't have a delete option), you should tap "more" and open the
>     question in a Web browser to delete it.
> - If you cannot delete your question, then there must be an upvoted answer, multiple answers, or an answer with an awarded bounty.
>     Deleting the question also deletes the answers. Deleting the answers
>     undoes the hard work other people have put in to answer your question,
>     and reverses the reputation they have earned too. This is not fair to
>     the answerers of your question

So, isn't this a case of wrong moderation and should not the post be restored?

**EDIT:**

Yet another question which was deleted by a moderator. This question too has an answer with positive score.

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32967/are-there-non-vaishnavites-devotional-compositions-that-contain-denigration-of-o/32972

Comment: Do you want your answer back?

Comment: I see a comment by mod under the question "**at your request** I'm deleting your _answer_" maybe mod mistyped it as answer instead of question. And "at your request" seems op wanted to delete it.

Comment: If I try to undelete the question, it says: "A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted" So only the concerned mod can resolve this one.

Comment: I think the other Mods also can .. If it is not resolved here I will hv to write to the CMs .. @sv.

Comment: undeleted the question.

Comment: Thanks but isn't an answer also required here? @TheDestroyer

Comment: @TheDestroyer I have added another example in my Q .. Pls do the needful

Comment: Don't link questions with rude and abusive content. Rude questions should be deleted. The answerer shows no discretion on what is rude or opinion based not. A question should have some criteria. Ping the moderator who deleted and there are 3 mods on the site.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Which portion of the Q is actually considered rude? I don't find anything .. so might be be "rude" is having here special definition? .. going by the usual usage of the word nothing is rude IMO .. here we have posts which even have words like "Who is this Vivekananda man .." but those posts are retained and I don't hv any problem with it, given that the answer is useful for many readers.. so I need to know what makes the Q "rude"

Comment: @TheDestroyer yeah there should be an answer here as why that undelete happen as right now this post owner making it a ground to get all random post undelete for him without separate discussion.

Comment: @Rickross you want to promote denigration of other believes here? That post is downright is with bad taste and we should not promote it just for rep.

Comment: The edit you added to this question is improper since the actual question is already solved (as the question you mentioned in the starting is already deleted), you may probably post a separate meta question for another one.

Comment: Oh I thought exactly the other way round .. I thought that a new post on the current issue was not needed @Pandya because the issue was similar .. a Q was again deleted in spite of having an upvoted answer ..  so do u suggest posting a separate post?